# Django Trying to re-use same webpage for several different listviews

Tags: python, html, django

Just stared with python /django. But trying to be more clever than I have competence for. So if someone has the time to educate me, I would appreciate it. I have a main model to handle "work orders". Then I have subsets of data that is linked to each order. I have then generated a html template where I can see an order and all subsets of data in a list view.

Now I'm trying to generate one generic HTML-template for the list views of all type (model) of data, instead of creating one HTML-template for each model of data. I thought I could define the variables through context_data.

Even if not complete I think you understand what I'm trying to do with the below code.

Otherwise the HTML-template and the views are working.

Views.py

```
class WO_TravelView(ListView):
    template_name = 'TravelLaborPartsLists.html'
    model = WorkOrderTravel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get('str')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list'] = WorkOrderTravel.objects.filter(wo_num=id_).order_by('wo_travel_slug')
        context['page'] = 'Travel logged for'
        context['string'] = id_
        context['label'] = 'Work order-instance / Start / Stop '
        context['data1'] = 'item.wo_travel_slug'
        context['data2'] = 'item.wo_travel_start'
        context['data3'] = 'item.wo_travel_stop'
        return context


class WO_PartsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'TravelLaborPartsLists.html'
    model = WorkOrderParts

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get('str')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list'] = WorkOrderParts.objects.filter(wo_num=id_).order_by('wo_travel_slug')
        context['page'] = 'Parts included in order'
        context['string'] = id_
        context['label'] = 'Operation / Partnumber / Qty '
        context['data1'] = 'item.wo_part_op'
        context['data2'] = 'item.wo_part_id'
        context['data3'] = 'item.wo_part_qty'
        return context
```

HTML

```
    <h1>{{ page }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ string }}</h1>

    <l2> {{label}}  </l2>

{% for item in list %}
     <p>{{data1}} - <a >{{data2}}</a>- {{data3}}  </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear for me what you want to achieve at the end but I can give you a clue as direction to think.

First, you can define serializer(s) that will represent columns you need from models. Might be as simple as that:

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializer

class WorkOrderTravelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.WorkOrderTravel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then - when you get your objects, you need to serialize them. For example:

**views.py**

```
orders = WorkOrderTravel.objects.filter(wo_num=id_).order_by('wo_travel_slug')
data = WorkOrderTravelSerializer(orders, many=True).data
```

`data` will now contain `list` of `json/dict` items - each of them represent on object of `WorkOrderTravel`

Now when you have your columns and data - you may pass them to context:

```
context = {
    'work_order': {
        'columns': list(data[0].keys()),  # names of columns are keys of dict
        'data': [[x for x in d.values()] for d in data]  # data of columns are values of the dict
    }
}
```

Same can be repeated for other models. (You can even define a common serializer which will get you all fields of each model)

Now you can create the template which will accept your context:

**list_template.html**

```
{% for column in obj.columns %}
 <p>{{ column }}</p>
{% endfor }

{% for row in obj.data %}
<p>{{ data }}</p> # or whatever way you want.. it can be table for example
{% endfor %}
```

**index.html**

```
{% include 'list_template.html' with obj='work_order'}
{% include 'list_template.html' with obj='work_order_parts'}
```

Thus, `list_template.html` can be reused for other models.

Again, it's rather an example/direction for further thinking depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of Egor worked well. Since I at the same time implemented a standard filtering functionality to the lists. I found it easier, even if I can't judge if it s a good or bad solution. At least it works.

I decided that I only wanted a limited number of fields, so I standardised them to 5. Then since I wanted better columns names I also defined a heading for each subset (class) of data. So now I use the same template for 8 different sets of data.

views.py

```py
qs = Model.objects.filter(id=id)

context = { 
    'queryset': qs.values(
        'modelfield1',
        'modelfield2',
        'modelfield5',
        'modelfield6',
        'modelfield7',
     ),
    'ListHeader': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}
```

This way I could define different fields and headings for each set of data. That I then used simple code to render out with some spacer.

in HTML template

```html
<h5>{{ ListHeader }}</h5>
<hr/>
{% for item in queryset %}
    {% for value in item.values %}<td>..{{ value }}..|</td>{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```